# Simple algorithm for reliable communications

Tags: serial-port, communication

So, I have worked on large systems in the past, like an iso stack session layer, and something like that is too big for what I need, but I do have some understanding of the big picture. What I have now is a serial point to point communications link, where some component is dropping data (often).

So I am going to have to write my own, reliable delivery system using it for transport. Can someone point me in the directions for basic algorithms, or even give a clue as to what they are called? I tried a Google, but end up with post graduate theories on genetic algorithms and such. I need the basics. e.g. 10-20 lines of pure C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the sending side;

```
/////////////////////////////////////////  XBee logging
void dataLog(int idx, int t, float f)
{
    ubyte stx[2] = { 0x10, 0x02 };
    ubyte etx[2] = { 0x10, 0x03 };

    nxtWriteRawHS(stx, 2, 1);
    wait1Msec(1);

    nxtWriteRawHS(idx, 2, 1);
    wait1Msec(1);

    nxtWriteRawHS(t, 2, 1);
    wait1Msec(1);

    nxtWriteRawHS(f, 4, 1);
    wait1Msec(1);

    nxtWriteRawHS(etx, 2, 1);
    wait1Msec(1);
}
```

on the receiving side

```
void XBeeMonitorTask()
        {
            int[] lastTick = Enumerable.Repeat<int>(int.MaxValue, 10).ToArray();
            int[] wrapCounter = new int[10];


            while (!XBeeMonitorEnd)
            {
                if (XBee != null && XBee.BytesToRead >= expectedMessageSize)
                {
                    // read a data element, parse, add it to collection, see above for message format
                    if (XBee.BaseStream.Read(XBeeIncoming, 0, expectedMessageSize) != expectedMessageSize)
                        throw new InvalidProgramException();

                    //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(XBeeIncoming, 0, expectedMessageSize));

                    if ((XBeeIncoming[0] != 0x10 && XBeeIncoming[1] != 0x02) ||  // dle stx
                        (XBeeIncoming[10] != 0x10 && XBeeIncoming[11] != 0x03))   // dle etx
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("recover sync");
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int b = XBee.BaseStream.ReadByte();
                            if (b == 0x10)
                            {
                                int c = XBee.BaseStream.ReadByte();
                                if (c == 0x03)
                                    break;     // realigned (maybe)
                            }
                        }
                        continue;   // resume at loop start
                    }

                    UInt16 idx = BitConverter.ToUInt16(XBeeIncoming, 2);
                    UInt16 tick = BitConverter.ToUInt16(XBeeIncoming, 4);
                    Single val = BitConverter.ToSingle(XBeeIncoming, 6);

                    if (tick < lastTick[idx])
                        wrapCounter[idx]++;
                    lastTick[idx] = tick;

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => DataAdd(idx, tick * wrapCounter[idx], val)));
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2);  // surely we can up with the NXT
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [XMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM). It's old, it's bad, but it is widely supported both in hardware and in software, with libraries available for literally every language and market niche.
2. [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) - High-Level Data Link Control. It's the protocol which has fathered lots of reliable protocols over the last 3 decades, including the TCP/IP. You can't use it directly, but it is a template how to develop your own protocol. Basic premise is:

   - every data byte (or packet) is numbered
   - both sides of communication maintain locally two numbers: last received and last sent
   - every packet contains the copy of two number
   - every successful transmission is confirmed by sending back an empty (or not) packet with the updated numbers
   - if transmission is not confirmed within some timeout, send again.

   For special handling (synchronization) add flags to the packet (often only one bit is sufficient, to tell that the packet is special and use). And do not forget the CRC.

---

Neither of the protocols has any kind of session support. But you can introduce one by simply adding another layer - a simple state machine and a timer:

- session starts with a special packet
- there should be at least one (potentially empty) packet within specified timeout
- if this side hasn't sent a packet within the timeout/2, send an empty packet
- if there was no packet seen from the other side of communication within the timeout, the session has been termianted
- one can use another special packet for graceful session termination

That is as simple as session control can get.

Comment: HDLC started as SDLC (IBM mainframes). I helped debug that :)  Later in life I wrote a ISO session layer for the FAA.  But otherwise, not a bad idea, just 3 years late :)

Comment: "just 3 years late" - I do not mind it going unnoticed. XMODEM is a mandatory mention for the topics like that. And it is 10-20 lines of code. If interoperability isn't required, drop in a proper CRC and it would still do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There are (IMO) two aspects to this question.

Firstly, if data is being dropped then I'd look at resolving the hardware issues first, as otherwise you'll have GIGO

As for the comms protocols, your post suggests a fairly trivial system?  Are you wanting to validate data (parity, sumcheck?) or are you trying to include error correction?

If validation is all that is required, I've got reliable systems running using RS232 and CRC8 sumchecks - in which case [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974082/best-8-bit-supplemental-checksum-for-crc8-protected-packet) probably helps

Comment: I have no control over the hardware, otherwise I would agree. I have to use what I have.  I am at least aware of using the eighth bit of a transmission to indicate a control code, combined with some 'start of text/ end of text' control code, followed by 7-bit data (which could be encoded 8-bit data. I was looking for something simple along those lines without having to create it myself. CRC8 would be fine for verification, but I am not that far along yet, got to get the data before I try to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If some components are droping data in a serial point to point link, there must exist some bugs in your code.

Firstly, you should comfirm that there is no problem in the physical layer's communication

Secondly, you need some konwledge about data communication theroy such like ARQ(automatic request retransmission)

Comment: well that is terribly arrogant. What law makes it a bug in my code? I'm not saying there isn't but its a big leap to assume it when you have no idea what the components are in my serial link. How about a small processor running at 99% cpu utilization, that is not interrupt driven? What bug in my code would cause that to fail?

Comment: I'm sorry about saying that. According to my experience, RS-232 point to point link is not likely to drop data. A good worked serial link

Comment: I'm sorry about saying that. According to my experience, RS-232 point to point link is not likely to drop data. A goog worked serial link will not suffer from data droping. If data in serial link is droping and is not as your expcection, then there may (sorry about "must" in perivious answer) exist some bugs in your code. I'm not English native speaker, and I apologize for improper word using.

Comment: yes, thanks for that. it may be a language difference. My code may indeed have an error, and there is probably also a very unreliable rs-232 link I have no control over. I have now verified in a simple terminal program, the data is also being lost, and my code is not involved (and someone else has verified this with the same hardware (XBee by the way). So yes I may have an error, but there are errors prior to my code as well. And I need to program around those errors.

Comment: Can you confirm that your terminal program was connected directly to the output, not at the other end of a cable (to eliminate cable loss)?

Answer (score 0):

Further thoughts, after considering your response to the first two answers... this does indicate hardware problems, and no amount of clever code is going to fix that.

I suggest you get an oscilloscope onto the link, which should help to determine where the fault lies. In particular look at the baud rate of the two sides (Tx, Rx) to ensure that they are within spec... auto-baud is often a problem?!

But look to see if drop out is regular, or can be sync-ed with any other activity.

Comment: It was/is indeed an overloaded CPU as I suspected. As I drop the sampling rate of sensor data, the errors decrease. I did eventually write my own code I will post as an answer. I'm just surprised no one else mentioned it.

Comment: Just to complete the answer, I think this means that the problem was at the Tx end?

Comment: yes. it may not be the xbees specifically, but an rs485 in between the cpu and the xbee that is load sensitive.